# How to pass SQS.new() to a function in Go?

Tags: go, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, aws-sdk-go

I have created a new sqs client using Go SDK for SQS

```
    svc := sqs.New(sess)
```

Now what will be the signature of the function which accepts this svc as a parameter ?

I tried `func(svc *SQS)` and `func(svc SQS)` , but its not working.

In the documentation its mentioned that `SQS.new(session)` returns a `*SQS` type.
What should be the type of svc then ?

Comment: We really can't tell what the problem is. Please show some code. But in general, it'll be something like `func(s *sqs.SQS)` (you're missing the package)

Comment: Yes. I missed the package. It should be func(s *sqs.SQS). Thanks for the quick response. A newbie in go here.